# What makes a semiconductor?

Tags: semiconductors

[Wikipedia says the following:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide-bandgap_semiconductor)

> Conventional semiconductors like silicon have a bandgap in the range of 1 - 1.5 electronvolt (eV), whereas wide-bandgap materials have bandgaps in the range of 2 - 4 eV.

According to [this table of semiconductor materials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_semiconductor_materials#Table_of_semiconductor_materials), however, there are semiconductors with both higher and lower band gaps, ranging from 0 - 6.36 eV. Where is the line? What is the criteria for determining whether or not something is a semiconductor?

Comment: what is the highest resistance of a conductor? the lowest resistance of an insulator? when does slow become fast? when does blue become violet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no actual hard line I'd be aware of that tells semiconductors from non-conductors in terms of bandgap.

In the end, it's a definition up to the author of any text. It **might** be helpful to think of things in practical terms (e.g. "can I make a PN junction out of this?"), but that really just brings you further down into subjective statements.

So,

> Where is the line?

Wherever it's sensible to put it in the context you're working with.